# ListView and R string directory

Tags: android, string, listview

I have a project (meaning an android app) created and used a custom `ListView` with three `TextView UI` for each column. But the app is also designed to support multi-language (at least three) using `strings.xml` file to fetch the selected language when user selects. Thus, the case here is, I have to write for the `ListView String [] example {"a", "b", "c"}` in java. I tried to do something like this `String [] example {R.string.a, R.string. b, R.string. c}` but the compiler says `Error " illegal array "`.

Now my question: Is it possible to reference the `String [] { }` of the `ListView` to `strings.XML` files.

Thank in advance and any example code or link I'm appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements of the array are constant, you can make string array in strings.xml and access that array in code.

Put the following in **strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="example">
        <item>a</item>
        <item>b</item>
        <item>c</item>
</string-array>
```

Access this array in code as:

```
String examples[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.example);
```

Comment: Thank you and I will tty later.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use the direct reference to the `String` array, you have to get the value of `String resource` via `getString()`

like this

```
String[] example = {
     getString(R.string.a), getString(R.string.b), getString(R.string.c)
};
```